# Nginx Ingress for Kubernetes "Connection refused"

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Was there a recent change to Nginx Ingress? Out of the blue I'm now getting "Connection refused" errors. I thought it was my own configuration which worked on a previous cluster.

Instead I decided to follow this tutorial [GKE NGINX INGRESS](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke) and I'm getting the same result.

```
$ kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                            DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
default       hello-app                       1         1         1            1           13m
default       nginx-ingress-controller        1         1         1            1           12m
default       nginx-ingress-default-backend   1         1         1            0           12m
```

I see the default-backend isn't running but I don't know enough about Kubernetes to know if that's what's preventing everything from working properly.

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                      AGE
hello-app                       ClusterIP      10.31.255.90    <none>         8080/TCP                     14m
kubernetes                      ClusterIP      10.31.240.1     <none>         443/TCP                      19m
nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer   10.31.251.198   35.227.50.24   80:31285/TCP,443:30966/TCP   14m
nginx-ingress-default-backend   ClusterIP      10.31.242.167   <none>         80/TCP                       14m
```

Finally:

```
$ kubectl get ing
NAME               HOSTS     ADDRESS         PORTS     AGE
ingress-resource   *         35.237.184.85   80        10m
```

According to the tutorial I should just be able to go to [here](http://35.237.184.85/hello) to receive a 200 and [here](http://35.237.184.85/test) to get a 404.

I've left the links live so you all can see them.

```
$ curl -I http://35.237.184.85/hello
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.237.184.85 port 80: Connection refused
```

I swear everything worked before and the only thing I can think of is that something from the teller install of nginx-ingress changed.

Please, any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: You'll want to provide the logs from the pods, starting with `nginx-ingress-default-backend`, because very likely whatever is making that angry is making the ingress controller angry

Answer (score 16):

That's because you are trying the request against the IP address created by the Ingress. Your entrypoint is the LoadBalancer type service created IP.

Try `curl -I http://35.227.50.24/hello`. That's where you will get 200.

Comment: Is the LoadBalancer service IP where an A record should point for a domain? I thought traffic was supposed to hit the ingress IP, especially if you want SSL.

Comment: `LoadBalancer` type service points to the Ingress Controller, and from there it's redirected to the right service.

Answer (score -2):

OK so 6k views and this is not right. Let's fix this :

> I see the default-backend isn't running but I don't know enough about Kubernetes to know if that's what's preventing everything from working properly.

The defaut-backend is what serves thos hello and healthz pages. Not runnig = no pages

> Is the LoadBalancer service IP where an A record should point for a domain? I thought traffic was supposed to hit the ingress IP, especially if you want SSL.

Yes you should always point to the ingress' IP. That's the point of ingress they handle named based http(s) request to route to proper services and handling (un the case of https) TLS/SSL stuff. Make sure you have a certificate autority like cert-manager configured on your cluster if you plan on doing this.